# SQL Server 2012 Dynamic Pivot Table with multiple subqueries and row 'headers' - can this be done?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I've been assigned development of a query that will result in a table with the region, district, and client populating Columns A,B,C with remaining columns showing the Campaign Name as the column header (Row 1). Management wants both Contact Name and Date of Contacts in the body of the pivot table. Like this:

```
Region  |District   |ClientID   |Campaign1  |Campaign2  |Campaign3
========|===========|===========|===========|===========|===========
1       |A          |830        |   NULL    |   NULL    |   NULL        
========|===========|===========|===========|===========|===========
1       |A          |832        |Name One   |   NULL    |Name One   
        |           |           |Date       |           |Date           
========|===========|===========|===========|===========|===========
1       |A          |833        |   NULL    |   NULL    |   NULL    
========|===========|===========|===========|===========|===========
1       |A          |834        |   NULL    |   NULL    |   NULL    
========|===========|===========|===========|===========|===========
1       |A          |837        |Name Two   |   NULL    |   NULL    
        |           |           |Date       |           |           
========|===========|===========|===========|===========|===========
1       |A          |841        |   NULL    |   NULL    |   NULL    
========|===========|===========|===========|===========|===========
2       |K          |262        |   NULL    |   NULL    |   NULL        
========|===========|===========|===========|===========|===========
2       |L          |266        |   NULL    |   NULL    |   NULL                   
        |           |           |           |           |            
========|===========|===========|===========|===========|===========
```

I'm new in this position. I'm relatively at a beginner level with SQL Server. I'm not sure of the limits of SQL Server 2012's capability.

Thus far, I've been able to get these results from the query that follows it:

```
|ClientID   |Campaign1  |Campaign2  |Campaign3  |Campaign4  |
|===========|===========|===========|===========|===========|
|830        |   NULL    |   NULL    |   NULL    |   NULL    |
|===========|===========|===========|===========|===========|
|832        |Name One   |   NULL    |Name One   |Name One   | 
|===========|===========|===========|===========|===========|
|833        |   NULL    |   NULL    |   NULL    |   NULL    |
|===========|===========|===========|===========|===========|
|834        |   NULL    |   NULL    |   NULL    |   NULL    |
|===========|===========|===========|===========|===========|
|837        |Name Two   |   NULL    |   NULL    |   NULL    |
|===========|===========|===========|===========|===========|
|841        |   NULL    |   NULL    |   NULL    |   NULL    |
|===========|===========|===========|===========|===========|
|262        |   NULL    |   NULL    |   NULL    |   NULL    |
|===========|===========|===========|===========|===========|
|266        |   NULL    |   NULL    |   NULL    |Name Six   |
|===========|===========|===========|===========|===========|
```

Current Query:

```
IF Object_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp') is not null
drop table dbo.#temp

SELECT * 
INTO #temp
FROM
   (
   SELECT MC.Region,MC.District,MS.ClientID,ML.CampaignName,MCL.ContactName
   FROM MnfstClient MC
   LEFT JOIN ManifestSummary MS on MC.ClientID=MS.ClientID      
   LEFT JOIN MnfstList ML on ML.FileDetailID=MS.FileID 
     and MS.ControlGroupFlag=0
   LEFT JOIN MnfstClientList MCL on MS.ClientID=MCL.ClientID 
     and ML.ListID=MCL.ListID
WHERE ML.InHomeDate Between '2016-04-01' and '2017-03-31'
GROUP By MC.Region,MC.District,MS.ClientID,ML.CampaignName,MCL.ContactName) A   
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.CampaignName)
        FROM #temp c
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')
SET @query = 'SELECT ClientID, ' + @cols + ' from 
        (
            SELECT
                 Region
                 ,District 
                 ,ClientID
                 ,ContactName
                 ,CampaignName
            FROM #temp
       ) x
        PIVOT 
        (
             max(ContactName)
            for CampaignName in (' + @cols + ')
        ) p '
EXECUTE(@query)
```

Here's what's in #temp when I run the 'SELECT INTO' statement:

```
+--------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------+-------+
| Region | District | ClientID | CampaignName | ContactName | Date  |
+--------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------+-------+
|      1 | A        |      830 | Campaign1    | null        | Date  |
|      1 | A        |      830 | Campaign2    | null        | Date  |
|      1 | A        |      830 | Campaign3    | null        | Date  |
|      1 | A        |      832 | Campaign1    | Name One    | Date  |
|      1 | A        |      832 | Campaign2    | null        | Date  |
|      1 | A        |      832 | Campaign3    | Name One    | Date  |
|      1 | A        |      833 | Campaign1    | null        | Date  |
|      1 | A        |      833 | Campaign2    | null        | Date  |
|      1 | A        |      833 | Campaign3    | null        | Date  |
|      1 | A        |      834 | Campaign1    | null        | Date  |
|      1 | A        |      834 | Campaign2    | null        | Date  |
|      1 | A        |      834 | Campaign3    | null        | Date  |
|      1 | A        |      837 | Campaign1    | Name Two    | Date  |
|      1 | A        |      837 | Campaign2    | null        | Date  |
|      1 | A        |      837 | Campaign3    | null        | Date  |
|      1 | A        |      841 | Campaign1    | null        | Date  |
|      1 | A        |      841 | Campaign2    | null        | Date  |
|      1 | A        |      841 | Campaign3    | null        | Date  |
|      2 | K        |      262 | Campaign1    | null        | Date  |
|      2 | K        |      841 | Campaign2    | null        | Date  |
|      2 | K        |      841 | Campaign3    | null        | Date  |
|      2 | L        |      841 | Campaign1    | null        | Date  |
|      2 | L        |      841 | Campaign2    | null        | Date  |
|      2 | L        |      841 | Campaign3    | null        | Date  |
+--------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------+-------+
```

So there you have it. If I can't get the query results to look as desired, I will need to run the query, dump results into Excel along with a table of Regions, Districts, Clients and use VLOOKUPs. The end users can't/won't do that.  It would thus, be my job to run the query weekly, and make the Excel modifications.  (and, for me, work=BAD)

So, what's the answer?  Can the complexity of the desired pivot be achieved?

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: What does the data going into the `#temp` look like?  It's going to be hard to get the final result without seeing some sample of the data.  Also I'd try writing this as a hard-coded version first, before trying to tackle a dynamic SQL version.

Comment: Thanks, bluefeet.

I added the data in #temp after the query in the original question.

(can you tell I'm also new to stackoverflow? I don't know what all is needed and how to achieve the desired look)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you can get the desired result by concatenating the `ContactName` and `Date` columns together.  Once they are concatenated in your subquery, then you will use that new column to get final result. Changing your query to:

```
SET @query = 'SELECT Region, District, ClientId, ' + @cols + ' 
              from 
              (
                  SELECT
                       Region
                       ,District 
                       ,ClientID
                       ,ContactName = ContactName + '' '' + Date -- concatenated column
                       ,CampaignName
                  FROM #yourquery
             ) x
              PIVOT 
              (
                   max(ContactName)
                  for CampaignName in (' + @cols + ')
              ) p '
              
EXECUTE(@query)
```

[See Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/646837#resultSets) with both a static and a dynamic version.

Comment: This works perfectly, it both adds the identifying columns to the left and brings together for the aggregated value, the Name and Date.

I'm grateful!

Comment: @MelissaPazen If this worked for you, please consider accepting this as answer, so others can benefit and also this will show appreciation for time and effort to help.